# Jquery/Jquery Mobile doesn't work when hosting on Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, firebase

I'm kinda new to hosting web apps online. I've currently build a mobile app using JQuery Mobile. It work totally fine when opening locally to chrome but when I host it with Firebase, the JQuery mobile doesn't seem to work. Is this because I don't have the files locally? I have linked to the JQuery Library using the online links. For Example:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Try it with `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: I've tried this, still doesn't work for some reason.